# sorting files on bash

Tags: bash, unix, sorting, cut

I have a bunch of files and would like to sort them according to their date represented in their file name as "2013-03-29_13-56-30". I am using `bash`.

```
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-03-29_13-56-30.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-12-03_17-01-51.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-04_13-49-58.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-04_14-25-51.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-05_10-06-33.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-05_13-49-49.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-08-09_17-48-54.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-11-10_09-46-33.jar
```

Thanks

---

I am not sure but `sort -n` seems enough because of the same prefix in all my files. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you give a little bit more detail about what you're doing? As it stands, those names *will* be sorted by the date (because the date is the only difference in their names) if you use a glob or even `ls` to display them.

Comment: I just want to write same as @kojiro . if you want to sort the text in your question. `sort input` would work because all prefixes are same. and your dateformat is `yyyy-mm-dd hh mm ss`

Comment: I guess the operative question is, are you actually working with these files, or are they really just a list of lines in a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the filenames in a file already, and they are disordered, then using `sort` as in fedorqui's answer will do the trick. But if you have the files on the filesystem, then any tools you use to enumerate them will sort them for you:

```
$ echo *
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-03-29_13-56-30.jar myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-04_13-49-58.jar myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-04_14-25-51.jar myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-05_10-06-33.jar myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-05_13-49-49.jar myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-08-09_17-48-54.jar myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-11-10_09-46-33.jar myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-12-03_17-01-51.jar
$ ls
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-03-29_13-56-30.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-04_13-49-58.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-04_14-25-51.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-05_10-06-33.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-04-05_13-49-49.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-08-09_17-48-54.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-11-10_09-46-33.jar
myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-V2013-12-03_17-01-51.jar
```

Now, one thing that can affect this is the `LC_COLLATE` environment variable. If you're unsure, set it to `C`.